# MariaDB Galera on Minikube: mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm, minikube, galera

I want to deploy a MariaDB Galera instance onto a local Minikube cluster with 3 nodes via Helm.
I used the following command for that:

```
helm install my-release bitnami/mariadb-galera --set rootUser.password=test --set db.name=test
```

The problem is, if I do that I get the following error in the log:

```
mariadb 10:27:41.60 
mariadb 10:27:41.60 Welcome to the Bitnami mariadb-galera container
mariadb 10:27:41.60 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera
mariadb 10:27:41.60 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb-galera/issues
mariadb 10:27:41.61 
mariadb 10:27:41.61 INFO  ==> ** Starting MariaDB setup **
mariadb 10:27:41.64 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_*/MARIADB_* env vars
mariadb 10:27:41.67 INFO  ==> Initializing mariadb database
mkdir: cannot create directory '/bitnami/mariadb/data': Permission denied
```

The site of the image lists the possibility to use an extra init container to fix that ([Link](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/mariadb-galera#extra-init-containers)).

So I came up with the following configuration:

mariadb-galera-init-config.yaml

```
extraInitContainers:
- name: initcontainer
  image: bitnami/minideb
  command: ["chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mariadb/"]
```

The problem is that when I run the command with this configuration:

```
helm install my-release bitnami/mariadb-galera --set rootUser.password=test --set db.name=test -f mariadb-galera-init-config.yaml
```

I get the following error on the Minikube dashboard:

```
Error: failed to start container "initcontainer": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mariadb/": stat chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mariadb/: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I don't know how to fix this configuration file, or if there is some other better way to get this working...

Comment: What user were you running as when doing the install?

Comment: I used my default non-root user on the local system. Just tried doing it with root, but there I cannot access the minikube cluster, nor start a new one, because docker doesn't allow being run with root privileges.

Comment: Correction: Got it to run with root priviledges, but the same problem with mkdir still persists.

Comment: Check permissions on the directory and its parent directory.  It may have been previously created by your non-root installation.  Use `chown` and/or `chmod` to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case someone has issues with this, may I suggest running a initContainer before.

```
 initContainers:
      - name: mariadb-create-directory-structure
        image: busybox
        command:
          [
            "sh",
            "-c",
            "mkdir -p /bitnami/mariadb/data && chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami",
          ]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /bitnami
```